# Find average of columns in a 2D list

Tags: python

Can someone help me find the average of columns in a 2D list. I really have no idea how to find this one. I know how to sum for each row but not for each column.
Here is the question:
There is the cities below with the rainfall for a number of days which is find in a file

```
city day1 day2
Rhil 15.0 18.0
Moka 12.5 13.5
```

I need to find the average rainfall over all the regions for each day.
The first part of the question was to read the file, fill the data in a 2D list and calculate the total rainfall for each region.
the calculated values for the total rainfall for each region.
Here is the first part of the code:

```
fil = open('rainfall.dat.txt','r')
data=[]
for line in fil.readlines():
    details=line.split()
    row=[]
    row.append(details[0])
    row.append(eval(details[1]))
    row.append(eval(details[2]))
    total_rainfall=eval(details[1])+eval(details[2])
    row.append(total_rainfall)
    data.append(row)
```

I'm a bit new to python and if someone could explain me how to find the average rainfall over all regions for each day in the simplest way is much appreciated.
I've searched for answers on the site but the code are complicated and not explained well.

Comment: Why do you `eval` everything? Be specific: use `float`. Please be specific about the question you're asking; do you know how to calculate an average? Have you made any attempts to implement that logic?

Comment: ok but can you help me?

Comment: The average will be half the total rainfall as you're summing 2 days' rainfall

Comment: I'm certainly not prepared to just write your code for you. Review [ask], and clarify your issue per my comment above.

Comment: I am just asking how to find the average of each column and it is as the question was settled

Comment: I understand the question, but SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. We aren't here to do your homework for you, and *really* aren't here to teach you basic maths. So, again, please clarify your question per the guidance available. If it can't be brought on topic per the [help/on-topic], just delete it.

Comment: `[sum(v) / len(data) for v in zip(*[u[1:] for u in data])]`

Comment: I answered you, and I think that is what you wanted to know. But you really shouldn't ask such questions on SO. That's what you've got so many down votes.

Comment: @PM2Ring : Oh, come on, you wouldn't want to zip() if you have extra big dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of two things:

1.
Enter your data in lists representing columns, not rows:

```
l = [
    [1,2,3,4], # Column 1 - not a row
    [5,6,7,8]] # Colum 2 - not a row
```

In this case, you know what to do. (for col in l: print (1.0*sum(col))/len(col))

2.
Else, you do it as in any language:

```
l = [
    [1, 4, 7], # row 1
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9]]

ncols = len(l[0])
nrows = len(l)
# Sum all elements in each column:
results = ncols*[0] # sums per column, afterwards avgs
for col in xrange(ncols):
    for row in xrange(nrows):
        results[col] += l[row][col]
# Then calculate averages:
# * nrows is also number of elements in every col:
nelem = float(nrows)
results = [s/nelem for s in results]
```

Or even better:

```
results = ncols*[0] # avgs per column
nelem = float(nrows)
for col in xrange(ncols):
    for row in xrange(nrows):
        results[col] += l[row][col]
    results[col] /= nelem

print results
```

Output is:

```
[2.0, 5.0, 8.0]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and advice. Will take note

Comment: And yes, do use float(), not eval(). eval() is dangerous. Also, it would be faster if you just do: line = f.readline().split(); row = map(float, line[1:]) . ([1:] to eliminate first column) Even faster if you go line by line in: lines = f.read().splitlines(). Then you can get the matrix immediately as: l = [map(float, line.split()[1:]) for line in lines] . Using append() manually slows you down and limits number of columns you are loading.

Answer (score -1):

```
[numpy.average(float(data[x][y]) for x in range(len(data))]) for y in range(len(data[0]))]
```

Comment: Please format your code and while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.